# Getting graphical Point of Listview items

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a `ListView` control on my form and I am trying to get either a `Point` or even better, a `Rectangle` of each **visible** item in my ListView. Anyone know of a trick to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        foreach (ListViewItem item in myListView.Items)
        {
            Rectangle result = item.Bounds;
            if(result.IntersectsWith(myListView.ClientRectangle))
            {
                //there you go
            }
        }
```

More about the `Bounds` you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.bounds.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is handle the `ListView.DrawSubItem` event, which gives me access to a `DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e` instance with a `e.Bounds` property giving me the rectangle you are asking for.

If you don't want to do any drawing on your own just set `e.DrawDefault = true;`

Here is an example of the results:
[image: ListView DrawSubItem]

Comment: +1 This would work too for what I needed but I implemented zmilojko's answer for my scenario